# Problem with CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

Tags: kotlin, exception, kotlin-coroutines

im new in kotlin. Druing studying i got this kind of exception

```kotlin
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while trying to handle coroutine exception
Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module with the Main dispatcher had failed to initialize. For tests Dispatchers.setMain from kotlinx-coroutines-test module can be used
```

That is my code

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

    println("1")
    scope.launch { println("2") }
    println("3")
}
```

What's wrong with that?

I changed scope declaration to

```kotlin
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
```

and it's working, could anyone explain me why i cant use Dispatchers.Main in that case?

Answer (score 3):

`Dispatchers.Main` is only available on each platform under certain conditions. You can check the documentation about this:

> Access to this property may throw an IllegalStateException if no main dispatchers are present in the classpath.
>
> Depending on platform and classpath, it can be mapped to different dispatchers:
>
> - On JS and Native it is equivalent to the Default dispatcher.
> - On JVM it is either the Android main thread dispatcher, JavaFx or Swing EDT dispatcher. It is chosen by the ServiceLoader.
>
> In order to work with the Main dispatcher, the following artifact should be added to the project runtime dependencies:
>
> - kotlinx-coroutines-android — for Android Main thread dispatcher
> - kotlinx-coroutines-javafx — for JavaFx Application thread dispatcher
> - kotlinx-coroutines-swing — for Swing EDT dispatcher

https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-main.html

So for example, when running an app on Android this will be available as a dispatcher based on the main `Looper` but in a test or `main` function it will be absent and throw the stated exception.

Your code sample works when using `Dispatchers.Default` because this is always available on all platforms (hence the "default").